# How to ignore a http header line with missing colon separator in golang

Tags: http, go

I am facing a problem in golang http server where client is sending a http request with invalid parameters in header. The request parameters are as follows:

```
GET /a-53-qf21489190x38856_2/yy HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80
User-Agent: mot-w845
Connection: Keep-Alive
Profile: http://10.213.2.68
X-MDN9035445271
accept: application/vnd.wap.mms-message
accept-language: en
accept-charset: US-ASCII, ISO-8859-1, UTF-8

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Connection: close
```

Here X-MDN9035445271 doesn't contain colon (:) separator, because of this server is returning bad request. Is there any way to ignore such kind of header and process the request normally.

Comment: Probably not with package net/http. The simplest solutions is to fix upstream. Or implement your own HTTP (forking net/http). Good luck with that!

Comment: The proper way to handle such a request is with a 400 response code, which seems to be what's happening. Anything else is no longer called HTTP, since the response to an invalid request is so specifically defined within the HTTP spec.  So if you want to do something differently, you should not use the `net/http` package.

Comment: Thanks @Volker for you suggestions. I have forked net/http and did changes in net/textproto/reader.go to ignore such line where colon (:) separator is not present and continue with rest lines instead of throwing error.

Comment: I would not change your code to handle a bug in a client.  If you must you can insert nginx as a reverse proxy to remove the header: stackoverflow.com/questions/44536548/how-to-remove-client-headers-in-nginx-before-passing-request-to-upstream-server